# Error when creating a LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list

So for data structure practice in different languages, I decided to create a Linked List in python.

Now here is my code so far, it is still far from done, but I've encountered this error and I cant seem to point out to myself where it is coming from:

```
class LinkedNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headNode = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.headNode == None

    def addToHead(self, value):
        head = LinkedNode(value)

    def removeFromHead(self):
        head = self.headNode
        self.headNode = self.headNode.nextNode
        return head

    def addToTail(self, value):
        if self.headNode == None:
            self.addToHead(value)
        else:
            tmp = self.headNode
            while tmp.nextNode != None:
                tmp = tmp.nextNode
            tmp.nextNode = LinkedNode(value)

    def empty(self):
        self.headNode = None

    def contains(self, value):
        tmp = self.headNode
        while tmp.nextNode != None:
            if tmp.value == value:
                return true
            tmp = tmp.nextNode
        return False

    def toString(self):
        tmp = self.headNode
        buffer = '['
        while tmp.nextNode != None:
            buffer = buffer + str(tmp.value) + ', '
            tmp = tmp.nextNode
        buffer = buffer + ']'

list = LinkedList()
list.addToHead(1)
list.addToHead(2)
list.addToTail(3)
list.toString()
```

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "path/linkedList.py", line 52, in 
>       list.toString()
>
> File "path/linkedList.py", line 44, in toString
>
> ```
> while tmp.nextNode != None:
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nextNode'
>   [Finished in 0.138s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, to answer your question, this is exactly why you're getting the error:

You are doing `head = LinkedNode(value)`, expecting the `LinkedList`'s `head` to be overwritten. But instead, what happens is that you create a local variable named `head` and assign it the value of `LinkedNode(value)`. As a result, `head` is always `None`. And you obviously can't do `None.nextNode` (because it ain't an object).

**Solution**: What you actually need is `self.head = LinkedNode(value)`. `self` is a reference to the object you're working with.

2. Secondly, there are several things wrong about your code. For instance:

a. By simply setting the `head` to the new node, you lose reference to the previously existing nodes.

**Solution**: What you need is:

```
def addToHead(self, value):
    tmp = LinkedNode(value)
    tmp.nextNode = self.headNode
    self.headNode = tmp
```

b. `toString` is a popular way of representing objects as strings, in other programming languages, but the *pythonic* way of doing it is by overriding the `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods for the object.

**Solution** (I've stuck with your format, although it could use some changing ;):

```
def __repr__(self):
    tmp = self.headNode
    buffer = []
    while tmp is not None:
        buffer.append(tmp.value)
        tmp = tmp.nextNode
    return "[" + ", ".join(map(str, buffer)) + "]"
```

c. There are several things wrong about the `toString` method (`headNode` is not being printed, will fail `headNode` being `None` etc.), but I'm not gonna try and fix them, as we have the solution above.

Comment: Ahh i see what you mean by the 'pythonic' way of doing things and that way i would just do `print(repr(list))` or `str` if i chose to use that as well. What would be a better thing to do? Would people be comfortable with a toString representation as well as using a pythonic representation alongside?

Comment: It's always advised not to have code duplication (having both `__str__()` and `toString`). Plus, you don't even have to do `print(repr(list))`. A simple `print(list)` would automatically invoke the `__str__()` method :)

Comment: Ahh okay thats good to know! I'll stick with the `__str__()` method then!

Answer (score 1):

Your addToHead method had no side effects. Possibly you meant

```
def addToHead(self, value): 
    head = LinkedNode(value)
    head.nextNode = self.headNode
    self.headNode = head
```

Also, toString will crash for empty lists.

Comment: I think there is also an issue with this. The head may not even exist so the nextNode would be null anyways

Comment: Yes, if headNode is None it means that you're inserting into an empty list, and head.nextNode should be None because after inserting there will be only one node (which is the head)